# « Ça a fucké le chien » : fonction et apport du chien au sens ?

Tags: sens, québec, vulgarité

En français, l'apport du [*chien*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chien) est sans équivoque dans bien des [expressions](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chien/15295/locution) :

> Un mal de chien. [grand]
>  Avoir du chien. [du mordant, de la gueule]
>  Une vie de chien. [misérable]
>  Être d'une humeur de chien. [massacrante]
>  Entre chien et loup. [le moment où on ne peut les distinguer]
>  Comme un chien dans un jeu de
>   quille. [mal à propos]
>  
>   Réserver à quelqu'un un chien de sa chienne. [la vengeance]
>   Se regarder en chiens de faïence. [fixement, avec agressivité]
>   Chien ! [l'injure]
>   Nom d'un chien ! [juron]

On fait souvent référence à la vie difficile, au comportement ou au rang de l'animal dans tel ou tel contexte etc. ; on sait que *[l]e chien aboie, clabaude, glapit (chiot), grogne, gronde, hurle, jappe* ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4667)) et ça peut aussi donner le ton. Souvent il complète un nom (est donc introduit par la préposition *de*) et on comprend aisément sa fonction grammaticale dans l'expression et/ou son apport sémantique.

---

> Ça a *fucké* **le chien**. [Québec, vulg., pour un truc populaire comme *a foiré* : échouer, tourner
>   court]

Le verbe [foirer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foirer) est intransitif, contrairement à [foutre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foutre). Au Québec on peut dire « *avoir mal en chien* » (beaucoup) et on pourrait aussi bien dire *en chien* dans l'exemple même si c'est peu usuel. Sauf que le chien y  occupe plutôt la position d'un complément direct et on a l'article *le*.  Quelqu'un sait comment ça s'analyse ?

---

- Quel est la **fonction** et l'**apport au sens** de ***(le) chien*** dans « Ça a fucké le chien » ?
- Est-ce que [*foutre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foutre)(fr.)/[*sacrer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/sacrer)(qc.) *le camp* (déguerpir) est utile pour comprendre la tournure avec le complément ?

  - Quelle est la relation entre le verbe foutre et le *camp* ?
  - Le *chien* a-t-il une fonction similaire au *camp* dans la phrase ?

Comment: Cela me semble plus venir de la traduction anglaise littérale de « niquer »/« baiser », qui aura la même tournure. Juste un COD (qui).

Comment: Le rôle du chien ? Pas agréable…

Comment: Good example of Quebecois losing its French structure. C'est une structure qui vient de l'anglais.

Comment: The structure is the same as: That takes the cake. or: That will float your boat. And that is English structure not French structure. it's just not French structure to say: quelque chose a [verbe d'action] le [objet]. It doesn't mean: something screwed up the dog. The Ça in French refers to a THAT in English. That showed you! Like that, see? English. :)

Comment: @Lambie I hear you but _la rouille a endommagé la carrosserie_ is full on French. Is _foirer_ an action verb... ? Please provide an answer with explanations, as comments are not indexed, are poorly formatted and detract from the Q&A. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Where did you get or hear this expression? It's structure is off. Also, do people in Quebec even use that verb?

Comment: Sorry, but I am an interpreter, lived in France 16 years and studied at the Sorbonne. I am not telling you; I am saying it; It is my opinion. Alors, je pige un peu quand même....c'est pour ça que je dis que la structure de la phrase  n'est pas une structure française. Larme a dit pareil. Chuispas la seule à le dire.....

Comment: D'autres pistes de solutions aussi sur ce [blog](http://oreilletendue.com/2012/04/30/du-chien-et-de-ses-usages-au-quebec/). Merci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m at a loss to answer your questions concerning *foutre/sacrer* (other than I think the function of *chien* is **only technically** similar to *camp*), but  the structure of the phrase in question is similar to:
["{that} sucked/sucks **the big one**"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sucked+the+big+one) & ["{that} bites/bit **the big one**"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+the+big+one) (both links to *The Free Dictionary*),
where although “the big one”  is **technically** the direct object of “sucked/bite” used transitively, I see it serving really more as an adverb intensifying the intransitive sense of *sucked* & *bites* when used as slang in "That sucks/That bites" to comment negatively about something:
  “that [majorly] sucked/bit…[big time]….[royally],”
so maybe “le chien” could be serving to intensify (and not just complement) *fucké* in “Ça a [fucké le chien](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fucker_le_chien)” (oui, au moins "fucker le chien" existe d’après Wikipedia):
“Ça a [royalement/vraiment/vachement(chienement??)] fucké/foiré/merdé.”

(cf: the usage of “au maximum” and “en pagaille” following  “foiré,” **technically** as indirect objects, but to my ear they are serving to intensify that intransitive verb, along the lines of “to the max” in English.

(Please note that although I’ve used **technically** bolded several times above, I must admit that I really don’t know what I mean by it here…maybe “in the strictest sense of the term”?)

Notwithstanding the above “analysis,” in an arguably half-hearted attempt to invoke the (or at least “an”) alternative, I’d offer a perhaps simpler "explanation" together with a supporting expression that I find to be perhaps more similar in structure to the phrase in question than “Foutre le camp,” to-wit:
“[Va] manger [de] la merde/marde.”

The above phrase uses a verb that usually involves pleasure together with a direct object  (hereinafter “COD”) that renders it much less pleasurable (unless one’s a fly!), just as “Fucker le chien” also uses a verb for  a usually pleasurable activity, but again much less so with this particular COD (unless one is also a  dog or is just “in” to such things! [??not that there’s anything wrong with that??]).

Granted, the two expressions differ in that the “vulgarity” of  “… manger …” is contained in the COD, while it's the verb that contains the "vulgarity" in the expression at issue, and I apologize if this difference is relevant to your question.

Again, however, both phrases do use a “pleasurable” verb with a seemingly incongruent/inconsistent COD to create their respective “vulgar” images and impact, whereas I’ve always (^^^until just now^^^)  taken the “foutre” in “foutre le camp” to mean,  not its “vulgar” (to have/possess sexually) sense used with an "inconsistent" COD, but rather  its “faire” sense (used congruently enough with the COD "le camp") that was/has become/is simply a harsh and “vulgar” way of saying “leve[r] le camp” or “décampe[r],”  most likely due to the word’s general use as a vulgar interjection and not to its direct association with "having/possessing sexually."

^^^(cf [re  my “until just now” above]: but then again, “faire” does not mean “**dé**faire,” and therefore the “faire” sense of “foutre” in “foutre le camp” should perhaps not have led me so quickly to “lever le camp” or “**dé**camper,” but rather to “faire le camp” or “camper” (sans les “**dé**")  which would mean the opposite of "foutre le camp."  So maybe the “foutre” in that phrase **is** being used in its pure “have/possess sexually” sense, which would support your claim/suspicion that the two phrases **are** similar enough in structure to justify further examination, e.g., is the structure of “foutre le camp” [at least when used to announce that someone him/herself is leaving a place in disgust [but not so much when ordering someone else to leave] similar/identical to the structure of the English “Fuck this place, [I’m outta here]”?)
 (all that to say that I’m obviously now at an even greater loss than before regarding “foutre le camp” and its relevancy to your good question)

Answer (score 1):

Étant Québécois, je dois préciser que si "fucker le chien" est une expression, c'en est une que je n'ai jamais entendue de ma vie.

Si je devais l'entendre, je présumerais que c'est juste le verbe *fucker* au sens de "foutre le bordel, mettre sans dessus-dessous" ou l'adjectif *fucké*, grosso modo "pervers, mal tourné". Ici, l'idée étant que le chien (et on parle d'un vrai chien, ce n'est pas une métaphore!) n'est pas en très bon état après la situation dont il est question: des dommages psychologiques ou physiques en résultent. Je pencherais plus pour le psychologique: le chien a des idées ou des réactions bizarres, voire carrément dangereuses (ce qui est pas mal la même chose que quand on dit de quelqu'un qu'il est *fucké*).

Autrement, je peux vaguement imaginer que ce soit une variante un peu exagérée de l'expression "son chien est mort", qui veut dire que la personne en question n'a plus aucune chance d'atteindre son but.

---

Si je saisis bien les commentaires ci-dessous, @L'aditdabenlà demandait plutôt si "chien" peut être ajouté à une expression de manière générale. Dans ce cas, la réponse est **oui**, mais la formulation était incorrecte: on dit *en chien*. Dans ce cas, c'est une **formule intensive** équivalente à celles qui emploient des sacres: *en crisse*, *en tabarnak* etc. C'est en fait une des nombreuses formes euphémistiques de ces expressions; *en sapristi* en serait aussi une.

*Ça a fucké en chien* signifie que la situation a vraiment, mais alors là *vraiment* foiré. *FUBAR*, comme diraient les Anglais: *fucked up beyond all recognition*.

Comment: Très intéressant. Alors, ce n'est pas une expression consacrée. Voilà une raison de plus que cela fait mal à l'oreille. :) Un truc mal tourné se dirait avec une autre structure: Ça a mal tourné. Ça a foiré. Alors que l'expression posté n'a pas une structure française....ni québecoise selon ce que vous dites....:)

Comment: Il ne s'agit point de tour d'ivoire. Mais apparement cela ne vous intéresse pas de savoir ce que l'on pense. Alors, je ne vais plus me fatiguer les méninges. :)

Comment: Vous avez dit là-haut: "quelqu'un sait comment ça s'analyse." Et bien, c'est exactement cela que j'essaie de faire. Si l'expression veut bien dire qu'un truc quelconque n'a pas marché ou a mal tourné, pour moi, la structure Ça a foiré est aux antipodes de: ça a fucké le chien! Cela a l'air d'un aphorisme, Pas de commentaires condescendants de ma part.

Comment: @Lambie D'accord, mais ceci est différent de la question de l'existence de l'expression en français du Québec. Merci.

Comment: Il me semble que la présence du chien n'a aucun rapport avec les sens possibles en français du genre: vie de chien. Au contraire, il me semble que l'idée est que même le chien (gentille créature) s'est fait baisé...et c'est pour ça que je pense que le truc n'est pas dans un imaginaire français....

Answer (score 0):

Dans l'expression *foutre le camp*, je dirais que c'est plutôt "foutre" qui occupe le rôle du chien : le rôle qui n'a pas beaucoup de signification à part la vulgarité qu'il apporte.

Le "camp", c'est le campement, le matériel, d'après [Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/foutre-ficher-le-camp.php), et *foutre* aurait le sens de prendre et non de planter. Foutre le camp, ficher le camp, prendre le camp, lever le camp. J'aurais plutôt cru que c'était le champ de bataille...

Comment: Non, je ne tentais pas de comparaison avec *ça a fucké le chien*, après tout, même si étymologiquement "fuck" n'est pas de même origine que "foutre" ou "fiche", l'usage est très semblable.